# UV flipped in parallax mapping

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm attempting to implement parallax mapping using the following shader pair in a deferred renderer, but as you can see in the attached image, the vertical shifting of uv coordinates for sampling is in the wrong direction.

[image]

The vertex shader is as follows:

```
#version 430 core
// Some drivers require the following
precision highp float;
// Model space data
layout (location = 0)in vec3 MSVertex;
layout (location = 1)in vec3 MSNormal;
layout (location = 2)in vec3 MSTangent;
layout (location = 3)in vec3 MSBiTangent;
layout (location = 4)in vec2 MSTexCoord;

uniform mat4 ModelTransform;
uniform mat4 ViewTransform;
uniform mat4 ProjTransform;
uniform vec3 camPos;
out xferBlock
{
    // Tangent space data
    vec3 TSViewPos;
    vec3 TSVertex;
    // World space data
    vec3 WSVertex;
    vec3 WSNormal;
    vec2 TexCoord;
    mat3 TBN;
} outdata;


void main()
{
    //mat3 normalMat = transpose(inverse(mat3(ModelTransform)));
    vec3 T = normalize(vec3(mat3(ModelTransform) * MSTangent));
    vec3 B = normalize(vec3(mat3(ModelTransform) * MSBiTangent));
    vec3 N = normalize(vec3(mat3(ModelTransform) * MSNormal));
    mat3 tbn = mat3(T, B, N);
    outdata.TBN = tbn;
    vec4 vert = ModelTransform * vec4(MSVertex,1.0);
    outdata.WSVertex = vert.xyz;
    outdata.WSNormal = normalize(mat3(ModelTransform) * MSNormal);
    outdata.TexCoord = MSTexCoord;
    outdata.TSViewPos = tbn * camPos;
    outdata.TSVertex = tbn * vert.xyz;
    gl_Position = ProjTransform * ViewTransform * vert;
}
```

and the fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core
// Some drivers require the following
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D colourMap;
uniform sampler2D specularMap;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;
uniform sampler2D heightMap;
uniform sampler2D glowMap;
uniform vec4 incolour;
layout (location = 0) out vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) out vec4 nColour;
layout (location = 2) out vec4 colour;
layout (location = 3) out vec4 specular;
layout (location = 4) out vec4 glow;

uniform int hasMaterial;

in xferBlock
{
    vec3 TSViewPos; 
    vec3 TSVertex;
    vec3 WSVertex;
    vec3 WSNormal;
    vec2 TexCoord;
    mat3 TBN;
}indata;

vec2 parallaxMapping(vec2 texCoords, vec3 viewDir)
{
    const float minLayers = 8.0;
    const float maxLayers = 32.0;
    float numLayers = mix(maxLayers, minLayers, abs(dot(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), viewDir))); 
    // calculate the size of each layer
    float layerDepth = 1.0 / numLayers;
    // depth of current layer
    float currentLayerDepth = 0.0;
    float height =  texture(heightMap, texCoords).r;    
    vec2 P = viewDir.xy / viewDir.z * 0.05;
//  P.y *= -1.0;
    vec2 deltaTexCoords = P / numLayers;
    vec2 currentTexCoords = texCoords;
    float currentDepthMapValue = height;
    while(currentLayerDepth < currentDepthMapValue)
    {
        // shift texture coordinates along direction of P
        currentTexCoords -= deltaTexCoords;
        // get depthmap value at current texture coordinates
        currentDepthMapValue = texture(heightMap, currentTexCoords).r;  
        // get depth of next layer
        currentLayerDepth += layerDepth;  
    }

    // get texture coordinates before collision (reverse operations)
    vec2 prevTexCoords = currentTexCoords + deltaTexCoords;

    // get depth after and before collision for linear interpolation
    float afterDepth  = currentDepthMapValue - currentLayerDepth;
    float beforeDepth = texture(heightMap, prevTexCoords).r - currentLayerDepth + layerDepth;

    // interpolation of texture coordinates
    float weight = afterDepth / (afterDepth - beforeDepth);
    vec2 finalTexCoords = prevTexCoords * weight + currentTexCoords * (1.0 - weight);

    return finalTexCoords;
}

void main()
{


    vec2 txc = indata.TexCoord;
    position = vec4(indata.WSVertex,1.0);
    if (hasMaterial == 1)
    {
        vec2 txc = parallaxMapping(indata.TexCoord,normalize(indata.TSViewPos - indata.TSVertex));
//      if(txc.x > 1.0 || txc.y > 1.0 || txc.x < 0.0 || txc.y < 0.0)
//          discard;
        colour = vec4(texture(colourMap,txc).rgb,1.0);
        vec3 normal_rgb = texture(normalMap,txc).rgb;
        normal_rgb = normalize(normal_rgb * 2.0 - 1.0);
        normal_rgb = normalize(indata.TBN * normal_rgb);
        specular = vec4(texture(specularMap,txc).rgb,1.0);
        nColour = vec4(normal_rgb,1.0);
        glow = vec4(texture(glowMap,txc).rgb,1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        colour = incolour;
        nColour = vec4(indata.WSNormal,1.0);
        specular = incolour;
    }
}
```

I can fix the issue by uncommenting `P.y *= -1.0;` in the `parallaxMapping` function, but this feels like a hack. As you can see in the image, the normals are correct (lighting is from above), so I'm at a loss to explain what is happening.

I've checked(and flipped) the v component in the obj model, and the tangent/bitangent vectors are generated by assimp on load.

I've also tried multiplying by the transpose of the TBN matrix, all with no effect.

I'm working from the tutorial found [here](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Parallax-Mapping).

Comment: "I can fix the issue by uncommenting `P.y *= -1.0;` .. but this feels like a hack" [this happens more often than we'd like to admit](https://twitter.com/mcclure111/status/1037178950584172545).

Comment: Oh no doubt there, but still, why do we not see such hacks in tutorials?